# Using a has_many and belongs_to relationship, I need to display the parameters of each resource in one index view

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 models, my schema looks like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140322214021) do

  create_table "transactions", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "product"
    t.integer  "price"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "barcode"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
  end

end
```

I want to display the user's name, the price of the transaction, and the product, all in the transactions index view. I particularly want to be able to add up the number of products the user has bought, as well as add the total price per user.

I am able to get the user object to print out, and the product and price. This is what I have so far:

```
<h1>Listing transactions</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Attendee</th>
      <th>Drink</th>
      <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @transactions.each do |transaction| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= transaction.user %></td>
        <td><%= transaction.product %></td>
        <td><%= transaction.price %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My create user action:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.transactions.build(params[:user][:transaction])
    if @user.save
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Thank you for signing up!"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end
```

My transactions index action:

```
  def index
   @transactions = Transaction.all

    respond_to do |fmt|
      fmt.json { render json: @transactions }
      fmt.html { render action: 'index' }
    end
  end
```

My user_params:

```
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :barcode)
  end
```

I have been able to do something like `<%= transaction.user.name %>` in the past with a join table, but its not happening here.

If I go to users#index, I get an error `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /users
Couldn't find User without an ID`

Thank you very much.

Comment: Using <%= transaction.user.name %> will surely gives you the name of the user.I dont see why it is working for you.Do you get any error?

Comment: Could you post the query filling `@transactions`? It probably lacks some `includes` or some `joins`, see the [`ActiveRecord` Query interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) for documentation on those.

Comment: I edited to show the error I get if navigating to the users#index

Comment: Could you post your user_params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /users Couldn't find User without an
>   ID

This could mean several things

---

**Routes**

You need to make sure you're accessing the right data

According to the [routes documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), you should only show collections of data in your `index` action. This error typically happens if you browse to `users/show` without any ID:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users, :transactions
```

If you're a beginner, this is how the RESTful routing structure would look:

[image]

---

**Data**

If you're accessing `@transactions = Transaction.all`, the issue may be with how you're storing your data:

```
create_table "transactions", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "product"
    t.integer  "price"
    t.integer  "user_id"
end
```

I don't think you're storing `user_id` for each transaction. When you create a new transaction, you need to pass the `user_id` to your model, otherwise it won't store the data correctly

We normally do this by using the [`.merge`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge) method in your params:

```
def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :barcode).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
end
```